# Android bluetooth send message

Tags: android, nfc

good morning.
I have a little question.
Is possible with android app, send message to all mobile nearly without pairing, and without visble mode?
The idea is send short message offering product in a shopping.
When the people is walking near the server it send a message offering a products.
Thanks!

Comment: No, that is not how bluetooth works...thankfully.

Comment: Use NFC tags. They seem perfect for your scenario. Hang NFC tags around the place, and people can hold their phones to it to get latest product offerings.

Answer (score 0):

> send message to all mobile nearly without pairing, and without visble
>   mode

No, this is not possible. For good reasons, security for example...

I do see that broadcasting out stuff over bluetooth that gets received by everyone would be a spammers wet dream, but fortunately the protocol doesn't allow such things.